# Modal Global Asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Criei um modal, que vou praticamente usar em todos os formulários do sistema, porém não sei como chamar esse modal nos formulários.
Este é o código do meu modal, a página chama Modal.aspx, e o modal é o #modalexclusao

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Modal.aspx.cs" Inherits="web_academia.Modal" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#modalexclusao").dialog();
      });
    </script>
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <div id="modalexclusao" title="Senha Exclusão">
      <p>Senha Exclusão teste form</p>
    </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

Como posso chamar ele no code-behind de outra página ?

Tentei desta forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modalexclusao').modal({
    url: 'Modal.aspx'
  });
});
```

Porém não aparece o modal.

Comment: Você já tentou usar o @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/SampleView.cshtml") ?   Só tem que ver como var jogar isso numa condicional... Mas essa é a função desse cara...

Comment: Utilizo webforms @DiegoSantos, atualizei da forma que tentei fazer, porém não funciona corretamente.

Comment: Puts, me desculpa faltou atenção. Vamos pesquisar

Comment: Tudo bem @DiegoSantos, estou pesquisando pra ver se encontro alguma solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tinha pensando na possibilidade, só colocar o modal na página Master, e deu certo, consigo chamar ele em qualquer página do projeto.